# How to import Salesforce report to SharePoint or OneDrive using Flows or Trigger

Tags: visual-workflow, integration, automation

Was wondering if anyone could advise on the best methodology to import Salesforce reports into SharePoint or OneDrive using Flows or Trigger, so that multiple people can collaborate on the same report.

Currently we're not using a connector to SharePoint, and are looking to move away from this due to potential security risks.

Any advice or recommendations will be greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance!